# Is it bad practice/inefficient to declare a method within an object than in a class?

Tags: javascript, class, object, oop

The way my code currently works, I simply declare an object and save it into an array like so:

```
cars = [];

for (var i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++) {
    cars[i] = {
        horsepower: 500,
        torque: 400,
        // various other aspects
    }
}
```

This approach had been sufficient up to this point, but I am planning on implementing methods for these objects and their properties. However, I'm unfamiliar with the inner working of object oriented programming and am unsure if declaring a method within each object of the array has disadvantages over using a class. To illustrate what I mean, here's the previous code with an added method:

```
cars = [];

for (var i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++) {
    cars[i] = {
        horsepower: 500,
        torque: 400,
        // various other aspects

        ignition () {
            console.log('The car has started');
        }
    }
}
```

So my question is: does declaring each object with a method take up additional memory than if they were declared using a class? Obviously, this wouldn't be much of a concern if there were only three car objects in the array, but it could be if there were thousands or more.

I'd appreciate any responses or links to documentation that would answer my question.

Comment: JavaScript uses Prototype-based OOP instead of Java-style OOP. Anyway: what you want is a prototype for `car`, so either use a constructor function (simpler, but old-style) or the new ES5+ `class` definitions.

Comment: Inefficient? Very, very slightly. Almost certainly not worth worrying about. So, bad practice? Likely no

Comment: @CertainPerformance So it _is_ less efficient? Can you clarify if it's worse for memory or something else entirely?

Comment: If you use `class` (or the more old-school `prototype`), the method will not be copied onto each object. So yes, using a class is more efficient. In 4 lines of code you will of course never notice the difference. But it's also about the intention of your code. If you want to program a car that has lots of properties and methods, then a `class` is a more readable, semantic way of coding that clearly states the intention of your code.

Comment: @Kokodoko Thank you for clearing that up for me. I'll be using classes much more often in the future, in that case.